# Xamarin.Forms Binding Collection in Custom Control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to create a custom control that has a ListView inside it and is populated in parent control. Here is the code:

Model used for testing (TestModel.cs):

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    public string TestText { get; set; }

    public TestModel(string text)
    {
        TestText = text;
    }
}
```

Custom control code (TestControl.xaml.cs):

```cs
public partial class TestControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TestItemsProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TestItems), typeof(ObservableCollection<TestModel>), typeof(TestControl), default);
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestItems
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<TestModel>)GetValue(TestItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(TestItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Custom control XAML (TestControl.xaml):

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SalesNet.Mobile.Controls.TestControl">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}"
                  x:Name="lv">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TestText}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

View model for the page containing the control (TestViewModel.cs):

```cs
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestModel> testModels;
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestModels
    {
       get { return testModels; }
       set { SetProperty(ref testModels, value); }
    }

    public Command LoadTestModels { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        var models = new List<TestModel>()
        {
            new TestModel("a"),
            new TestModel("b")
        };

        TestModels = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(models);
        LoadTestModels = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadTestModels());
    }

    private async Task ExecuteLoadTestModels()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        var models = new List<TestModel>()
        {
            new TestModel("a"),
            new TestModel("b"),
            new TestModel("c")
        };

        // I have tried this
        TestModels.Clear();
        foreach (var model in models)
           TestModels.Add(model);

        // And this
        TestModels = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(models);

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Page containing the control, code (TestPage.xaml.cs):

```cs
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    private TestViewModel viewModel;

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        viewModel.LoadTestModels.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Page that contains the control, XAML (TestPage.xaml):

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SalesNet.Mobile.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SalesNet.Mobile.Views.TestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <controls:TestControl TestItems="{Binding TestModels}"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem I'm having is that the collection is not propagated from parent to custom control. I have tried both re-declaring and re-populating the collection. This only happens with collections. I've also tried writing OnPropertyChanged event in the custom control (TestControl.xaml.cs), but it's not firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following method in your Custom Control

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TestItemsProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "TestItems",
                returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<TestModel>),
                declaringType: typeof(TestControl ),
                propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);
```

```
static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
            Console.WriteLine(newValue.ToString());
            var control = (View1)bindable;
            control.lv.ItemsSource = newValue as ObservableCollection<TestModel>;
}
```

And remove the line from the constructor

```
BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: This does work, thanks! Can you please explain why the property changed event is needed and why setting BindingContext to this needed to be removed?

Comment: This seems an existing issue of XF 4.x , I will check it again :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, I have been tearing my hair out for about 4 hours wondering why the binding into my user-control just doesn't work, but it works perfectly happily to all the platform controls on the page. This has fixed it. Is Binding in XF4 broken? I don't understand why the PropertyChanged event is needed, or the removal of BindingContext=this, either. It just doesn't seem to make sense. It feels like we're bypassing the system that should handle this. Can you clarify? (I'm on XF4.7.0.1239)

Comment: Apparently, when you want databinding between your own control and "outside", you cannot also use databinding *inside* your control. Instead you have to access subcontrols by name to set (or get) their values